# SQL query : get product data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server. First is `product` and another is `Productimage`.

In `ProductImage`, there could me more than one image for a single product.

Now I want **all** products and **only one** image for each product. So please help me to write such query.

Comment: Plz provide your schema details and the logic on the basis you expect to select one image out of many for a product.

Comment: How you will choose image for product?

Comment: Select tblProductMaster.* , tblCategoryMaster.CategoryName From tblProductMaster
  Inner Join tblCategoryMaster
  On tblProductMaster.CategoryID = tblCategoryMaster.CategoryID

Comment: now i want to add imageName from tblimage

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: k.. nxt time for sure.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.prodid,max(i.image) from product p inner join Productimage i
on p.prodid=i.prodid
group by p.prodid
```

or

```
select prodid,image from (
select p.prodid,i.image,row_number() over (order by p.prodid partition by p.prodid) as rn 
from product p inner join Productimage i
on p.prodid=i.prodid) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: @anand:- how did you figure it out that what is datatype of image column

Comment: ii have updated the query pls check.First i thought image column will have just the path of the image file.

Comment: Select tblProductMaster.* , tblCategoryMaster.CategoryName,MAX(tblImageMaster.ImageName) From tblProductMaster
  Inner Join tblCategoryMaster
  On tblProductMaster.CategoryID = tblCategoryMaster.CategoryID
  Inner join tblImageMaster
  on tblImageMaster.ProductID = tblProductMaster.ProductID
  group by tblProductMaster.ProductID

Comment: i'm also using join to add category name and written above query bt it is giving me error